# Is it appropriate to encrypt a file using identifierForVendor?

Tags: ios, cocoa, security, encryption

I'm pondering the correct way to encrypt a file in my application. The following applies to the data stored in the file:

- The data is not very sensitive
- The data can be recreated if lost (although it's very expensive)
- The file should only be readable by my application
- The file should not be readable by my application when copied to another device
- The application should not require the use of a device password for the keychain

An idea I have is to use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]` as the encryption key, since this should ensure my points above.

Is this a good way to do it? Please give me all reasons you can think of why I shouldn't do this!

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using it directly.

The reason why is that it may change under several circumstances like upgrading.

Still you can use it instead of a random generator to then store it in the key chain for future usage.

**Reference**

> The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them. The value can also change when installing test builds using Xcode or when installing an app on a device using ad-hoc distribution. Therefore, if your app stores the value of this property anywhere, you should gracefully handle situations where the identifier changes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor